# How to deserialize root JSON dynamic property name in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to deserialize the following JSON object in C#. I'm having trouble because the "0a6888c9-86c5-48e7-a6d9-da3cc39db1a0" is dynamic

```json
{
  "0a6888c9-86c5-48e7-a6d9-da3cc39db1a0": {
    "minPricePerNft": "100000000000000000",
    "amountForSale": "1",
    "loopringSaleInfo": {
      "minPricePerNftInWei": "100000000000000000",
      "amountForSale": "1"
    },
    "likeCount": 4
  }
}
```

I've tried making the following c# classes to no avail...:

```cs
   public class LoopringSaleInfo
    {
        public string? minPricePerNftInWei { get; set; }
        public string? amountForSale { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public string? minPricePerNft { get; set; }
        public string? amountForSale { get; set; }
        public LoopringSaleInfo? loopringSaleInfo { get; set; }
        public int likeCount { get; set; }
    }
    public class GameStopNftListing
    {
        public string? @class { get; set; }
        public Value? value { get; set; }
    }
```

Any tips?

The difference between this and other similar questions on here is the root property is dynamic. All the other answers I see start with a non dynamic root property...

Comment: See the duplicate - use `Dictionary<string, Value>`

Comment: I don't quiet understand the solution. Can you give me a code example?

Comment: Change the type you deserializing to to `Dictionary<string, Value>`.